# Smallest prime factor of $\lfloor e\uparrow e\uparrow e\uparrow e\rfloor$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, math-software, big-numbers

What is the smallest prime factor of $$\lfloor e\uparrow e\uparrow e\uparrow e\rfloor$$ To get this number start with $1$ and apply the $\exp$-funtion four times, then take the integer part. This number is an enormous number, having $$1\ 656\ 521$$ digits (Note that this happens to be a prime number!). I was curious and, for fun wanted to determine the smallest prime factor, expecting that I will soon find a prime factor.

But it turned out that the number has no prime factor below $10^9$.

> What is the smallest prime factor of the above number ? Can we do any better than trial division ?

A primilaty test will take long for such a large number and even the pollard-rho-method is slow (at least with PARI/GP). I would like to check the number with PFGW or with yafu, but I do not know how to copy such a large number such that yafu or PFGW can read it.

And maybe , this number has already been checked by someone. Who can give a link or helps to find a factor ?

Comment: Curiosity question: Do these questions ever get answered?

Comment: Nice Question, but what makes me sad is that I want to know the answer, but the answer is not known yet, but I hope such question will be answered soon.

Comment: Is $\uparrow$ exponentiation?  If not, what is it?

Comment: @badjohn It is exponentiation

Comment: Matt Parker on YouTube has an article on whether $\pi \uparrow \pi \uparrow \pi \uparrow \pi$ is an integer.  Spoiler alert: we don't know, it's too big.  https://youtu.be/BdHFLfv-ThQ?si=Kd17VOAPdgAzLh8L

Comment: I'll add, we *do* know that $e\uparrow e\uparrow e\uparrow e$ is not an integer, because it only has 1656521 digits (well within the precision capabilities of modern computers), while $\pi\uparrow\pi\uparrow\pi\uparrow\pi$ has $10^{18}$ digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass large numbers to yafu, ecm, and pfgw, by using a file input, and filling the file with the mountains of digits. It's a bit different for each program, but can be done if you're persistent.

I've taken the liberty of doing a bit of testing on my own, to see if I couldn't find the smallest factor myself:

I've done trial division up to $10^{10}$, no factors found.

Yafu seems to generally choke on a number so large, even disabling the Fermat's factorization steps and Rho steps, it seems to be hung on internal step that doesn't scale well to the millions of digits, which is kind of to be expected. It may eventually get through whatever it's hung on, but we really just want to run ECM, so I went ahead and did that itself instead.

I've completed around 50 ECM curves at B1 level 10000, which lets us know that, if our assumptions are correct, we would have likely found a factor if it were under 20 digits, but we're not certain yet. We're about 99.9% sure that there's no factor under 10^15, and 35.6% sure there's no factor under 10^20. I'm currently running 10 curves at B1 level 100000, but 24 hours has elapsed and it's still in stage 1, so it's unclear how long it will take to finish.

If those are finished and no factors are found, our "expected factor size" that we would expect to have found, if it exists, would be around 21 digits. And we could keep doing this and pushing the limit of our certainty until we either got lucky or bored.

But, we can also use the [Buchstab function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstab_function) to determine how unlucky we currently are, as it helps us count the number of positive integers less than or equal to x with no prime factor less than y. My understanding is that the ratio of these k-rough integers to the total integers is a good indicator of how likely it would be that a random integer chosen at this magnitude would be k-rough, or, in other words, how surprised we should be that we have or haven't found a factor yet. With respects to the randomness of our integer, I can't seem to think of any particular reason why the floor of a 4 times repeated exponentiation of a transcendental constant couldn't be considered a random integer, so we'll just roll with it.

We'll use this formula to estimate $\Phi(x,y)$, the number of positive integers less than or equal to x with no prime factor less than y:

$$\Phi(x,x^{1/u}) \sim \omega(u)\frac{x}{\log x^{1/u}}, \qquad x\to\infty.$$

$$x=\lfloor e^{e^{e^{e}}}\rfloor \approx 2.33150 \times 10^{1656520},\qquad x^{1/u}=10^{20}$$
$$u\approx82826$$

$$\omega(u)\to e^{-\gamma} \approx 0.561, \qquad u\to\infty.$$

$$\Phi(x,x^{1/u}) \approx 0.561\frac{\lfloor e^{e^{e^{e}}}\rfloor}{\log 10^{20}}\approx 2.84023 \times 10^{1656518}$$

$$\frac{2.84023 \times 10^{1656518}}{2.33150 \times 10^{1656520}} \approx 0.012181 \approx 1.2181 \%$$

Or, in other words, there is a 1.2% "chance" that a random number at this magnitude is $10^{20}$ rough, so it's pretty unusual that we haven't found a factor yet!

We also know that the prime density at x is $\frac{1}{ln(x)}$, and $\frac{1}{ln(e^{e^{e^{e}}})} \approx 2.621 \times 10^{-7}$, so we would also expect it to be unlikely that this number is prime, or about a 0.00002621% chance, but I'm running a primality test in pfgw to confirm, which should take around 5 hours on 4 threads.

Edit: the pfgw test has indeed confirmed the number is composite:

```
Generic modular reduction using generic reduction FMA3 FFT length 672K, Pass1=448, Pass2=1536, clm=4, 4 threads on A 5502842-bit number
2331504399007195....7434294745087021 is composite: RES64: [E50C04724466150F] (37852.0028s+5.9436s)
```

And the 100000 B1 ECM curves have failed due to running out of memory on my machine. So I'm retrying with some 50000 B1 curves, and if that fails, there are other ways I can manually tune the process to keep trying.

Edit2:
No factor found yet, there has been a known total of ECM curves ran on the numbers of:

- 100@1e4
- 20@1e5

Current t-level is 22.8

Comment: I am very astonished that ECM works on such numbers with a reasonable amount of time. Thank you for this answer !

Comment: I remember the Buchstab-function rather in context with smooth numbers. But I can confirm the final result : The probability that a huge random number is $10^{20}$-rough is in fact $0.0121919\cdots$ which is about $1:82$. In fact , when I attacked this problem I expected a soon answer and was baffled.

Comment: The probability is however independent of the magnitude of the given number , as long as it is huge enough.

Comment: Yep! ECM works because its time complexity scales with the size of the smallest factor of the number. In practice, it is also slowed by the size of the n, in our case $\lfloor e^{e^{e^{e}}}\rfloor$ (or eeeei), I believe due to the fact that all the operations are done modulo eeeei. We may also be able to run some useful p-1 tests, but my understanding is that they scale with the loglog of n as well as the prime bound.

Comment: True, my surprise was because the running time nevertheless increases fast with the number of digits (even if not more operations are needed). In particular , PARI/GP is almost useless if such numbers are to be handled.

Comment: Astonishing to see a 6-year-old question answered! (Even if with no factor found yet)

Comment: I happened upon this question because it came up when I googled "pfgw trial division", as I was trying to figure out why pfgw wasn't catching large even numbers I had been programmatically primality testing with pfgw. And since it had no answer and was interesting to me, I decided to give it a crack! As for my original query, I think pfgw has some internal logic to not do any trial div with numbers past a certain size or something, though it normally does do some amount of trial division by default. I never really got to the bottom of it, because I was nerd sniped by this question :)