# Is there another prime $p$ such that $S(p)$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

Denote $$S(p):=2^2+3^3+5^5+\cdots +p^p$$

$S(p)$ is prime for $p=3,7,89$.

> Is there another prime $p$ such that $S(p)$ is prime ? Is the number of primes $p$ such that $S(p)$ is prime, finite ?

Comment: I'm astonished there is a third case. I'm sure the probabilities indicate that the expected number is finite; effectively you have a number with no prior known divisibility roughly the size of $p^p$, which has a descending chance of being prime, $<(1/(p\ln p))$, in a population becoming sparse.

Comment: Up to what $p$ did you check?

Comment: Nothing more up to p < 10000 from what I see.

Comment: @DanaJ: For $p=10000$, then $S(p)$ has more than 40000 decimal digits. What primality test did you use? ECM?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I arrived at $5500$ , but apparently, DanaJ got much further.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII ECM is usually used to find factors. But with elliptic curves, prime proving is also possible. But the usual approach to decide whether a number is prime is the strong-probable-prime test. Only if a number passes it, we cannot be sure whether it is prime, although it is very likely in general. If a number fails that test, it must be composite.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII as Peter said.  I used ES BPSW, about 30 minutes total.  There are simple pretests, a M-R base 2 test, then ES Lucas.  Composites of this size will rarely make it past the M-R test.  If one had passed then 40k digits would be more problematic for further testing, but it's easy for composites.

Comment: @DanaJ Hi, Dana! Do you have interest/time for EnzoCreti's prime-finding project ? Or can you tell me how I can concatenate two Mersenne-numbers in factordb ? (The later would be helpful as well)

Comment: Does anyone know the syntax for summation in OPEN PFGW ?

Comment: @Peter I don't know which one you had in mind -- Enzo has one or more questions every single day so it would be impossible to keep up.  It's highly unlikely regardless as I'm already involved in prime gaps as well as generic software.  I don't know the syntax for concatenation on factordb if it does exist.  I hope you get an answer on your question about it.

Comment: @DanaJ I mean this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635516/numbers-n-of-the-form-10m2k%e2%88%9212k-1%e2%88%921-where-m-is-the-number-of/2636195#2636195

Comment: I double-checked the range upto $p=9\ 973$ and found no further prime either.

Comment: @Peter I started the search but I think that it will take 2 months for finishing the job.

Comment: @EnzoCreti Did you also download PARI/GP ?

Comment: @Peter no but isnt it even slower than PFGW?

Comment: @EnzoCreti Yes, but you can also verify sums, products etc with is apparently not supported by PFGW or factordb.

Comment: @EnzoCreti What do you think abouth this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480379/smallest-prime-factor-of-lfloor-e-uparrow-e-uparrow-e-uparrow-e-rfloor ?

Comment: @Peter impressive! That number is huge!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73886/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).