# Summation of prime to the prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let
$$S(t)=\sum_{k=1}^t p_k^{p_k}$$

Where $p_k$ is the kth prime number.
E.g. $S(2)=2^2+3^3=31$

Since $S(2)$ and $S(4)$ were both the $p+2$ of a twin prime.

Continued search with Pari/GP to test to $t=10^4$ and have found primes only for
$\{2,4,24\}$, $S(24)$ is not a twin.

Will $S(t)$ for $t>24$ always have a factor?

Comment: $S(10^4)$ has more than $500\ 000$ digits. This is a huge search limit and it will be difficult to find further primes. Since I guess that we cannot rule out small prime factors, a proof that there is no more such prime is probably out of reach.

Comment: I asked this question nearly $3$ years ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668289/is-there-another-prime-p-such-that-sp-is-prime)

Comment: Thank you Peter, for the information.  
Is there an analytical way to approach this problem?

Comment: No, we can do nothing more than search for another prime (after applying trial division)